Can't correctly print to serial UART using AVR-c on ATmega328P Arduino Uno
I'm trying to program an ATmega328P Arduino Uno "bare metal" to print to serial over the USB connection to my computer, however I only see replacement characters (�) being printed, both when  using screen /dev/ttyACM0 9600 and when using the Arduino IDE serial monitor. I've tried different baud rates to no avail, although the baud rate should be 9600. The TX LED flashes regularly, and the � are appearing at the same rate as expected.
I was following the serial print part of the guide: https://archive.md/wqcw6. Using the make instructions from the same guide resulted in no transmission at all, so I used a different make (shown below) which resulted in transmission but just the � being received. I suspect there's a baud rate issue being caused somewhere.
Here is my code:
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef F_CPU
#define F_CPU 16000000UL
#endif

#include <util/delay.h>

#define BAUD 9600

#include <util/setbaud.h>

int uart_putchar(char, FILE*);
void uart_init();

FILE output = FDEV_SETUP_STREAM(uart_putchar, NULL, _FDEV_SETUP_WRITE);

void uart_init(void) {
    UBRR0H = UBRRH_VALUE;
    UBRR0L = UBRRL_VALUE;
    UCSR0C = (1<<UCSZ01) | (1<<UCSZ00); // 8-bit data
    UCSR0B = (1<<TXEN0); // enable TX
}

int uart_putchar(char c, FILE *stream) {
    if (c == '\n') {
        uart_putchar('\r', stream);
    }
    loop_until_bit_is_set(UCSR0A, UDRE0);
    UDR0 = c;
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    uart_init();
    stdout = &output;

    while(1) {
        printf("Hello World!\n");
        _delay_ms(500);
    }
    return 0;
}


Here's my Makefile:
default:
    avr-gcc -Os -DF_CPU=16000000UL -mmcu=atmega328p -c -o serial-print.o serial-print.c 
    avr-gcc -o serial-print.bin serial-print.o
    avr-objcopy -O ihex -R .eeprom serial-print.bin serial-print.hex
    sudo avrdude -F -V -c arduino -p ATMEGA328P -P /dev/ttyACM0 -b 115200 -U flash:w:serial-print.hex


Any tips would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

a tip. if you have problems with the program, why not try w/o optimizations?

I just tried dropping the -Os on the avr-gcc if that's what you mean. Got a:
warning "Compiler optimizations disabled; functions from <util/delay.h> won't work as designed"
and nothing transmitted at all when it was flashed to the arduino, no LED blinking on the TX

This question is similar to: Linking multiple object files into a binary AVR GCC. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Parts of that question help in an indirect way but it's definitely different both in terms of what it's asking and in terms of what the solution given is. I don't see any need to edit my question.

I found the answer in this post here:
ATmega328P USART Transmit character printed repeatedly
Changing my Makefile to the following solved my problem:
avr-gcc -Os -DF_CPU=16000000UL -mmcu=atmega328p serial-print.c -o serial-print.bin
avr-objcopy -O ihex -R .eeprom serial-print.bin serial-print.hex
sudo avrdude -F -V -c arduino -p ATMEGA328P -P /dev/ttyACM0 -b 115200 -U flash:w:serial-print.hex


maybe you just have to repeat -DF_CPU=16000000UL -mmcu=atmega328p flags to the linker? because I do not see any difference with joining everything in one command.

your answer is not an answer, but a mindless repeat of some nonsense.

adding -g -mmcu=atmega328p to the second line in the original also works

"also works..." - means it solves your problem?

-g switch means adding gnu compatible debug symbols to the output. i'm writing it so that you not just copy someones makefiles verbatim, but learn something.
